# How to clear app data in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Q: How do I clear app data in Marshmallow [Android 6]?

I'm using the marshmallow developer preview and can't work out how to clear app data, there used to be an option in in the 'App Info' screen to clear the data but that is no longer in the developer and I'm guessing the soon to be released factory images.

Comment: Is this really a programming related question? Not sure if SO is the place to ask about how to use the latest version of Android

Comment: Yes, what if you want to start your app as a fresh install?

Comment: But then, what about: "How to create a text file in Android?" (I want to test my app with a text file, but I don't have a text file, how can I create one)... would you accept that question too?

Comment: Hi spences10 you need to go storage in App info, then you get option there for clear data and clear cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your app's screen in Settings, click "Storage", then click the "Clear Data" button on the subsequent screen. Note that there is also a separate "Clear Cache" button.

[image: Android 6.0 App Storage Screen]

Comment: Brilliant!! Can't believe I didn't find it!! Thanks